# SeatGeek Scraping Certificate Issue

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following code that used to work on my old computer, but now that I switched laptops it's pushing a certificate issue related to the client_id. Any idea how to fix this?

```
gameIds = [5316872]

url = 'https://seatgeek.com/rescraper/v2/listings'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(final, engine='xlsxwriter')

tables = []
for gameId in gameIds:
    payload = {
    '_include_seats': '1',
    'client_id': 'MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4',
    'id': '%s' %gameId,
    'sixpack_client_id': '93d1ab10-07dc-4482-bb89-b87c2b144e33'}
    
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData['listings'])
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=gameId)
    tables.append(df)
    print(gameId)

table = pd.concat(tables)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(final, engine='xlsxwriter')
table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Tickets')
writer.save()
print('Done')
```

Error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='seatgeek.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rescraper/v2/listings?
_include_seats=1&client_id=MTY2MnwxMzgzMzIwMTU4&id=5316872&sixpack_client_id=93d1ab10-07dc-4482-bb89-b87c2b144e33 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Comment: you did not define "final" variable. without pandas it works for me, probably were problems on sever side. also, if you are not afraid of interception you can try to change https to http

Comment: I defined 'final' outside of the above code (its a personal drive location). And adjusting the https to http did not resolve the issue for me..